# How to automate PDF printing

Tags: automation, printing, pdf

I'm looking to automate the printing of PDF's from a Windows 2008 Server to an IPP Printer.

- Are there any options for PDF printing built directly into the OS?
- Does anyone have experience with good PDF printing command line utilities?
- Is it possible to automate this using Adobe Reader?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Acrobat Reader has a "quiet" parameter, so you could do:

```
AcroRd32.exe /t "C:\test.pdf" "\\servername\printername"
```

in your batch file to print out pdfs from the command line.

Something like

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b *.pdf') do printit.bat %%a
```

Where printit.bat uses prints using reader then deletes the file (if you want it to).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to watch a directory you could use [WatchDirectory](http://www.watchdirectory.net/) which seems to support automatic PDF printing in conjunction with Adobe Reader.